# MySQL client is not connected (Mysql2:: Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

[image]I am facing issues with live site with MySQL.

We having 2 servers, the Server 1 went down, then we analysed the logs and found the below error.

MySQL client is not connected (Mysql2:: Error)

And another server which Server 2 able to communicate with MySQL in the same time. We saw the logs for that

What could be cause for the connection error in server 1?

How to resolve these type of issues?

Adding log files

```
I, [2023-06-15T06:07:30.674196 #5178]  INFO -- : 2023-06-15T06:07:30+0000: [Worker(delayed_job host:94656cbd8b56 pid:5178)] Error while reserving job: MySQL client is not connected
```

F, [2023-06-15T06:07:30.675210 #5178] FATAL -- : MySQL client is not connected (Mysql2::Error)
/home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:82:in `escape' /home/site/wwwroot/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:82:in` quote_string'

Comment: If the question not clear please let me know

Comment: Likely a network issue.  These happen. The server could have had an issue reaching the network, there could have been an issue in the network path, etc. Just need to help your application handle these gracefully, and report persistent issues as quickly as possible to someone who can look at them.